# How to get membership level id f a particular user

Tags: membership

How do I get membership level id of a particular user. I have tried

```
$user = get_userdata($userid);
$membership_id = $user->membership_level->ID;
```

but it gives a notice of `Trying to get property of non-object....`.
I am doing it through Ajax. I have googled it but does not found any solution. Anyone can help?

https://wordpress.org/plugins/paid-memberships-pro/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want `pmpro_getMembershipLevelsForUser` from [functions.php](https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/paid-memberships-pro/tags/1.8.9/includes/functions.php):

```
/* pmpro_getMembershipLevelsForUser() returns the membership levels for a user
 *
 * If $user_id is omitted, the value will be retrieved from $current_user.
 * By default it only includes active memberships.
 *
 * Return values:
 *      Success returns an array of level objects.
 *      Failure returns false.
 */
function pmpro_getMembershipLevelsForUser($user_id = NULL, $include_inactive = false)
{
```

Or there's `pmpro_getMembershipLevelForUser` if you only want the first level. Or if you actually want to test access then there's `pmpro_hasMembershipLevel` too.

As far as I can see these are all stored in separate tables with date ranges and other restrictions so there's no simple way to access them through normal WP user functions.

(And I expect there's documentation about all of these on their website here http://www.paidmembershipspro.com/documentation/ but it looks like you'll have to sign up.)

Comment: Yeah... I forgot to mention `pmpro_getMembershipLevelForUser($user_id);`. After watching my previous code I found this error. By the way thanks for your time.